# Conflicting Account Exists Locally

Tags: adduser

I have network user account and I was trying to add it to admin group, using a local admin account.

I accidentally typed `useradd` instead of `usermod`, and when I restarted my computer it gives error of `mci handler`.

I had to use the recovery mode, and when I try to ssh to that network account I get the conflicting account error.

Is it the problem with my Hdd?

Is there anything I can do without losing anything?

Comment: mci  is probably related RAM, but the account looks fixed now, based on me changing things as admin on recovery mod.